# Drawing an Ace card from a deck of 52 on the nth try

Tags: probability

I have the following question:

> We draw one card at a time without replacement from the top of a shuffled standard poker deck and stop when we draw an ace. Let $X$ be the number of cards we have drawn, then calculate the probabilities for $X=10$, $X=50$, and $X < 10$.

I have a theory as to how to solve the first one: calculate the probability of the drawing $10$ cards WITHOUT getting an ace, which has a probability of $\binom{48}{10} / \binom{52}{10}$, and subtracting this from $1$. For the other two, I am a little bit lost.

Regarding the second one, I think that if I draw $50$ cards from the deck, the probability of drawing an ace should be $1$, shouldn't it?

And unfortunately I'm lost on the last part. I would love a clue on this matter.

Thanks

Comment: Since there are four aces, the first ace must appear by the $49$th card.  Hence, the probability that the $50$th card is the first ace is $0$.

Comment: Hint for the last part:  compute the probability that there is no ace among the first $10$ and subtract.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig maybe its a problem with the phrasing of the question but from what I understand is that they are asking the probability of getting an Ace on the nth draw, rather than asking what is the probability of getting the first Ace (to me they are not the same question). So wouldn't it make sense that for the 50th draw it would be 100% probable that the draw is an Ace?

Comment: My understanding is that we draw cards until we obtain the first ace.  Hence, $P(X = 10)$ means that the first ace appears in the $10$th position.

Comment: @lulu wouldnt that just yield the same result as the first question of the problem? Could you elaborate a bit more on the subject?

Comment: As @N.F.Taussig points out, there is an indexing issue.  I thought that $X$ counted the cards drawn BEFORE getting the Ace, but on closer reading I think you are also counting the Ace.  Thus for the last part you want the probability that there is no Ace among the first $9$ (as the first Ace in slot $10$ would mean that $10$ cards were drawn).

Comment: No, this is not the same as the first part, as it allows for the first Ace to be anywhere in the first $9$ cards.  Granted, parts of the calculation overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(X = k)$ is the probability that the first ace appears in the $k$th position.

> What is $P(X = 10)$?

For the first ace to appear in the tenth position, we must first choose nine non-aces, then choose an ace with the tenth draw.  The probability that the first nine cards are not aces is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{48}{9}}{\dbinom{52}{9}}$$
The probability that one of the four aces is chosen as the tenth card from the $43$ remaining cards is 
$$\frac{4}{43}$$
Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{48}{9}}{\dbinom{52}{9}} \cdot \frac{4}{43}$$

> What is $P(X = 50)$?

Since there are four aces in the $52$-card deck, the first ace must appear no later than the $49$th position.  Hence, $P(X = 50) = 0$.

> What is $P(X < 10)$?

The probability that $P(X < 10)$ is found by subtracting the probability that the first nine cards are not aces from $1$.

> $$P(X < 10) = 1 - \frac{\dbinom{48}{9}}{\dbinom{52}{9}}$$

Comment: This seems to be computing the chance that there is exactly one ace among the 10 first cards drawn. But here we want that ace to come _last_ among those 10 cards, so you need to divide the probability by 10.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Have I fixed the error?

Comment: Yes, I think so.